# is it a 'for' or '.append()' bug in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I try to use `'uga'` as input(=text). I want to get `[['U','g','a'],['u','G','a'],['u','g','A']` as output.

I have tried this code :

```
text = 'uga'
abc = list(text)
out_list = []

for i in range (len(text)):
    out_list.append(abc)

x = out_list.copy()

for item in range(len(x)):
    x[item][item] = x[item][item].upper()
print(x)
```

after using that code I got `[['U', 'G', 'A'], ['U', 'G', 'A'], ['U', 'G', 'A']]` as the output.

If we cut the code...

```
text = 'uga'
abc = list(text)
out_list = []

for i in range (len(text)):
    out_list.append(abc)

x = out_list.copy()
print(x)
```

it will give `[['u', 'g', 'a'], ['u', 'g', 'a'], ['u', 'g', 'a']]` as the output.

after that I try to make the code without `append()`. I just make a new variable using this list --> `[['u', 'g', 'a'], ['u', 'g', 'a'], ['u', 'g', 'a']]` which is same as `x`

```
a = [['u', 'g', 'a'], ['u', 'g', 'a'], ['u', 'g', 'a']]
for item in range(len(a)):
    a[item][item] = a[item][item].upper()
print(a)
```

surprisingly I can get result which is `[['U', 'g', 'a'], ['u', 'G', 'a'], ['u', 'g', 'A']]`

after that I try again using append but manually, like this:

```
b = []
b.append(['u','g','a'])
b.append(['u','g','a'])
b.append(['u','g','a'])

for i in range (len(b)):
    b[i][i] = b[i][i].upper()

print(b)
```

the result is right too which is `[['U', 'g', 'a'], ['u', 'G', 'a'], ['u', 'g', 'A']]`

---

I don't know **why my first code give the wrong result**... because when I check the type of `x` , `a`, and `b` it same which is a list.
After that I check `a==b==x` it gives the result `True`

I also put them in the same code which is:

```
for i in range (len(something)):
    something[i][i] = something[i][i].upper()
```

I have thinking a lot and ask many of friends, but no body could know what happened..

I'm sorry because my English is not very good. Hope you could help me...

Thank you

Comment: In the first snippet, `out_list[0] is out_list[1]`. In the second, it is merely the case that `out_list[0] == out_list[1]`. See [Is there a difference between “==” and “is”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is). You need to copy `abc` so you have different sublists, not copy `out_list` (or use deepcopy). Check how your code runs in the visualizer [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) by stepping through it, and it should be abundantly clear. (Not writing an answer, because it will almost certainly be closed as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see what happens if you add a print statement in the second loop. The output the looks like this:

```
[['U', 'g', 'a'], ['U', 'g', 'a'], ['U', 'g', 'a']]
[['U', 'G', 'a'], ['U', 'G', 'a'], ['U', 'G', 'a']]
[['U', 'G', 'A'], ['U', 'G', 'A'], ['U', 'G', 'A']]
[['U', 'G', 'A'], ['U', 'G', 'A'], ['U', 'G', 'A']]
```

As you can see the values all change at the same time. That happens because you add the abc object to the array 3 times and don't copy it.